# Transpose a column to a line after detecting a pattern

Tags: awk, transpose

I have this text file format:

```
01  contig00041 1   878 +   YP_003990830.1  metalloendopeptidase, glycoprotease family  Geobacillus sp. Y4.1MC1 100.00  291 1   291 47  337 0.0 592 #line 1
01  contig00041 1241    3117    -   YP_002948419.1  ABC transporter Geobacillus sp. WCH70   84.94 #line 2
37.31   624 #line 3
260 1 #line 4
321 624 #line 5
532 23 #line 6
12  644 #line 7
270 0.0 #line 8
3e-37   1046 #line 9
154 #line 10
```

I have to detect a line containing 8 columns (line 2), and transpose the second column of the followning seven lines (lines 3 - 9) to the end of the 8-column line. And finally, exclude line 10. This pattern repeats along a large text file, but it is not frequent (30 time, in a file of 2000 lines). Is it possible doing it using awk?

The edited text file must look like the following text:

```
01  contig00041 1   878 +   YP_003990830.1  metalloendopeptidase, glycoprotease family  Geobacillus sp. Y4.1MC1 100.00  291 1   291 47  337 0.0 592 #line 1
01  contig00041 1241    3117    -   YP_002948419.1  ABC transporter Geobacillus sp. WCH70   84.94   624 1   624 23  644 0.0 1046 #line 2
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Ah, ok. Exclude line 10.

Comment: Is this the full file? Should line 10 be excluded because it's the last line, or because it only has one field, or for some other reason? Do the comments `#line 3` etc. exist in the actual file?

Comment: No, no comments. The original file is large. All the lines should look like line 1. However, it was not the case. The pattern demonstrated repeats occasionaly along the text file, like 30 times in a file containing more than 2000 lines.

Comment: Again - what is it about line 10 that tells us the script it should be excluded?

Comment: Line 10 has just one column.

Comment: So is your requirement really that any line with exactly 2 fields should have it's 2nd field appended to the previous line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** to only add the second column of the lines with two columns.

I think this does what you want:

```
awk 'NF >= 8 { a[++i] = $0 } NF == 2 { a[i] = a[i] " " $2 } END { for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) print a[j] }' file
```

For lines with more than 8 columns, add a new element to the array `a`. If the line has 2 columns, append the contents to the current array element. Once the whole file has been processed, go through the array and print all of the lines.

Output:

```
01  contig00041 1   878 +   YP_003990830.1  metalloendopeptidase, glycoprotease family  Geobacillus sp. Y4.1MC1 100.00  291 1   291 47  337 0.0 592
01  contig00041 1241    3117    -   YP_002948419.1  ABC transporter Geobacillus sp. WCH70   84.94 624 1 624 23 644 0.0 1046
```

Comment: Worked very well! In fact, I just saw that my original file is more complex than I thought. There are lines followed by more than eight lines of one and two columns (there is one of 30 lines!). Your code worked perfectly for it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Fernando no problem, glad it worked. Thanks for accepting my answer, don't forget you can also up vote any answers that you found useful.

Comment: I would like to vote, however I do not have enough reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NF == 12 { t = $0; for (i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) { r = getline; if (r < 1) break; t = t "\t" $2; } print t; next; } NF > 12' temp.txt
```

Output:

```
01  contig00041 1   878 +   YP_003990830.1  metalloendopeptidase, glycoprotease family  Geobacillus sp. Y4.1MC1 100.00  291 1   291 47  337 0.0 592
01  contig00041 1241    3117    -   YP_002948419.1  ABC transporter Geobacillus sp. WCH70   84.94       624     1       624     23      644     0.0 1046
```

- It would automatically print lines having more than 12 fields.
- If it detects lines having 12 fields, concatenate second column of other 7 lines with it and print.
- Ignore any other line.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I need just the second columns of lines 3-9. In your output both columns one and two are transposed.

Comment: As I said to Tom, my file is more complex than I thought. There are followed by more than eight 1-2 column lines. I dont know why, but your code was not able to fix this line: 01 contig00004 4900 5625 + ZP_02083926.1 hypothetical protein CLOBOL_01449 Clostridium bolteae ATCC BAA-613 65.38
26.36 234
220 7
26 240
238 4
273 237
491 8e-105
2e-17 323
89.4

Comment: Thank you anyway. The output was: 01 contig00004 4900 5625 + ZP_02083926.1 hypothetical protein CLOBOL_01449 Clostridium bolteae ATCC BAA-613 65.38